# How are the singular values of $A$ and $A^{T}$ related?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given a singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$, find a singular value decomposition for $A^T$. How are the singular values of $A$ and $A^T$ related?

So the singular value decomposition of $A^{T}$ is:

$$A^{T}= (U\Sigma V^T)^T
= (V^T)^T \Sigma^T U^T
= V\Sigma^T U^T$$

But how are they "related"? Other than having the same elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix of rank $s\le\min\{n,m\}$.
$$
A = U\Sigma V^T.
$$
We can take $U$ to be an $n\times s$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $V$ to be an $m\times s$ matrix with orthonormal columns (so that $V^T$ is an $s\times m$ matrix with orthonormal rows) and $\Sigma$ to be an $s\times s$ diagonal matrix (i.e. all entries not on the main diagonal are $0$).  Then we have
$$
A^T = V\Sigma^T U^T,
$$
but $\Sigma=\Sigma^T$, so
$$
A^T = V\Sigma U^T.
$$
The left singular vectors of $A$ are seen to be the right singular vectors of $A^T$ and vice-versa.

The singular *values* of $A^T$ are the same as the singular values of $A$ since in both cases they're the diagonal entries in $\Sigma$.

Comment: The same is true when using the unreduced SVD, i.e. where $U$ is $m \times m$, $V$ is $n \times n$, and $\Sigma$ is $m \times n$. In this case $\Sigma$ might have some zeros on the diagonal. The two conventions each have their merits.

Comment: @Ian : True, but it's neater this way.  There's a lot of arbitrariness in the "extra" columns added to $U$ and $V$, and that information is of no interest.  It's just an arbitrary choice of an orthonormal basis of the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by the columns that matter.

Comment: Well, the choice of convention begs a question: if $A$ is not full rank, does it have a singular value of zero or not? In the reduced convention it doesn't, in the unreduced convention it does.

Comment: @Ian : I an tempted to include as many columns in $U$ as in $A$, and as many columns in $V$ as rows in $A$.  I think there may be some contexts in which this matters, but I'm not sure what they are right now.  Maybe one of those occurs when noise perturbs the entries in $A$ thus resulting in a matrix of higher rank, and a sudden downward jump in the decreasing sequence of singular values tells you where that happens.